# React : I want to update state when user select 3rd option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to update the state value , For example if user select 3rd option from select then I want to update a state value . I tried but state value is not changing could someone please help me how to solve this problem . Thanks

**Code**

```
class Calendar extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            isCustomer:false
        }
    }
render(){
return(
  <select>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">1</option>
   <option value="3" onChange={this.setState({isCustomer:true})}>1</option>
  </select>
)}

export default Calendar
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, try my solution below and let me know that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using the `onChange` event within `select` (and not option). You can then check if the value selected is the third one.

Working example:

```js
class Calendar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isCustomer: false
    }
    
    onChange = ev => {
      this.setState(
        {isCustomer:ev.target.value === "3"},
        () => { console.log(this.state.isCustomer)
      })
    }
    
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <select onChange={this.onChange}>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">54</option>
           <option value="3">Customer</option>
          </select>
          {this.state.isCustomer && <input defaultValue="Hi customer :)"></input>}
        </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calendar/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Comment: Kudos for the snippet effort.

Comment: Haha, thank you. It's been a while since I've done one of those, had to dig up older answers to make it work somehow

Comment: @Treycos , Can you please show and hide Input based on condition

Comment: The... select itself ? Like, if 'customer' is selected, the entire ting disappears ?

Comment: No , Actually I want when user select option 3 then I want to show Input . If user select other option then I want to hide an input

Comment: Simply replace the `<p>` node with whatever you want (well, an input). I'll edit it

Comment: Well the snippet works fine with it... You may have done something wrong, I can't know what it is

Comment: Could you edit your question with the additional information ? (code, error)

Comment: Actually, Alert is not showing . When I console in browser `isCustomer` values is true but alert is not showing

Comment: If you just want to show an alert, you can put the call into the condition of the `onChange` function instead of the JSX

Comment: Actually , I just give an example of alert . I want to show input but it doesn't wokr

Comment: Just copy and past the line above : `{this.state.isCustomer && <input defaultValue="Hi customer :)"></input>}`
Its an inline `if`

Comment: actually , I am working on React-popup so in form the updated values is not coming when I refresh the page then Updated values is come . I want to re-render a form content when state is udpated

Answer (score 2):

You are calling function directly on change it will lead to infinite state what you can do is :

```
class Calendar extends Component {
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            isCustomer:false
        }
    } 
   handleChange = (e) => {
     console.log(e.target.value)
      if(e.target.value==="3"){
       this.setState({isCustomer:true})
      }
   } 

render(){
  console.log(this.state);
return(
  <select  onChange={this.handleChange}>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">1</option>
   <option value="3" >1</option>
  </select>
)
}    
}

export default Calendar
```

Code demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dxheff

Comment: could you please show and hide input based on condition

Comment: @Jonas what have you tried so far for show/hide the input?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `onChange` event on the select tag not the option tag.

Then apply some additional logic to your event-handler to check if the desired option was selected.

Here is the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sound-v0stt

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Calendar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isCustomer: false
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    if (e.target.value == 3) {
      this.setState({ isCustomer: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.isCustomer);
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.handleOnChange}>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">1</option>
          <option value="3">1</option>
        </select>
        {this.state.isCustomer ? <input placeholder="name" /> : ""}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Calendar />, rootElement);
```

For your specific issue with the alert(). Just trigger the alert in the call-back function like this:

```
  onChangeHandler = e => {
    if (e.target.value == 3) {
      this.setState(
        {
          isCustomer: true
        },
        () => alert("It is working")
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, one last thing . I want to hide and show input field. For example by default I want to hide field when user select option 3 I want to show it

Comment: Sure you can use a ternary operator to check against the updated state value. See updated answer. @Jonas

Comment: You can also use an inline `if` to show it, as seen in the answer above

Comment: Can you update your code above with what you've tried :) @Jonas

Comment: @Jonas I've updated my solution with how to use the `alert()` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First you cant embed event on option , so you've to bind onChange event on the select ragn
Second thing you have to pass a function inside your event not direct instructions ..

I dont know exactly what you want to achieve but may be the above snippet will help , it sets the `isCustomer` state only at  option value 3

```js
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isCustomer: false
    }
  }
  
  selectChange = (evt) => {
         
      let val = evt.target.value;
      

      this.setState({
        isCustomer: val === "3"
      }, () => {
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML ="state is :" + JSON.stringify(this.state);
      })
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <select onChange ={ (e) => this.selectChange(e) }  >
      <option value = "1" > 1 < /option>  
      <option value = "2" > 2 < /option>  
      <option value = "3"
       > 3 < /option>  
      </select>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Calendar / > , document.getElementById("calendar"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
<pre id="state"></pre>
```